# What is the default Broadcasting address used to setup a broadcast application

Tags: java, networking

I want to write a broadcast application.so that  i want to know the ,what can i put the broadcasting address and port number?.Basically I am planning to write a single server and multiple clients and the server broadcast a data gram into the multiple clients and based on the packet the clients should response to the server

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MulticastSocket Class to do this.Here is the example 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html

Comment: But the document didn't provide the default broadcast address